# How to pass the search results specific component session into another page

Tags: php

I have the following files:

file1.php: it includes search form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and 
file2 "search.php" is the file which submit the results:

```
<?php
require "../session.php";
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : "";
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Component WHERE (`ComName` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
$number = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
         $i=1;
echo "<p><h3>" ."There are ( <font color='red'>".$number ." </font>) matches to your search of" ."<font color='red'> $query </font>" ."</h3></p>"
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
$_SESSION['ComName']= $results['ComName'];
print_r ( "<p><h3>" ."<font color=yellow>" ."&nbsp" .$i."- </font>" ."<a href=\"ViewComponents.php?flag=Submit&status_Component=".$_SESSION['ComName']."\">" . str_ireplace($query, "<font color=red>$query</font>", $_SESSION['ComName']) .'</font>'."</h3>" ."</a>";
 $i++;

 } else{ 
echo "<p><h3>" ."Sorry there are no results for your search of " ."<font color='red'> $query</font>." ."</h3></p>"; 
}

}
?>
```

The question is when I click on specific component from the search result page such as component2; which should be passed to file3 "ViewComponents.php" but the file "ViewComponents.php shows only the last components session from the search results instead of the clicked component.

How to make the clicked component pass to other file "ViewComponents.php" instead of passing only the last component?

Comment: Can you post the part responsible for viewing the component in the "ViewComponents.php" file here?
You should avoid using mysql_* functions, since they are deprecated and removed from PHP 7.

Comment: the code is written using php5. Part of the file "ViewComponents.php" is: <?php

$temp_package=$_SESSION['ComName'];


$sql = "SELECT ProductName FROM Components where ComName='$temp_package' ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<br> NOTE: Our record shows that there are ( <font color='red'>".$number ." </font>) products versions include $temp_package.";
?><br /><br /><?

Answer (score 0):

There you go, the issue here is that you are fetching the component details using the `SESSION` array which as shown in your second file `search.php`, you keep in it only the last component name from the database.

On your `search.php` file, remove the unnecessary line

```
$_SESSION['ComName']= $results['ComName'];
```

And in the link change the passed `GET` parameter so that it gets it from the results array instead of the SESSION:

Here is what your search.php file should look like:

```
<?php
require "../session.php";
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : "";
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Component WHERE (`ComName` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
$number = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
         $i=1;
echo "<p><h3>" ."There are ( <font color='red'>".$number ." </font>) matches to your search of" ."<font color='red'> $query </font>" ."</h3></p>"
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
print_r ( "<p><h3>" ."<font color=yellow>" ."&nbsp" .$i."- </font>" ."<a href=\"ViewComponents.php?flag=Submit&status_Component=".$results['ComName']."\">" . str_ireplace($query, "<font color=red>$query</font>", $results['ComName']) .'</font>'."</h3>" ."</a>";
 $i++;

 } else{ 
echo "<p><h3>" ."Sorry there are no results for your search of " ."<font color='red'> $query</font>." ."</h3></p>"; 
}

}
?>
```

As for your main issue here, which is the `ViewComponent.php` file only showing the last component from the database, change the second line in that file so that the variable `$temp_package` gets the package name from the `GET` array instead of the `SESSION`, so this line:

```
$temp_package=$_SESSION['ComName'];
```

Becomes:

```
$temp_package=$_GET['ComName'];
```

That should do the job. In addition, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and removed from `PHP 7`, you should stop using them, try reading more about `MySQLi` or `PDO`.